# How can I visualize this complex geometry with mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

Let $\varepsilon$ be a complex number of small magnitude and let $1+\varepsilon$ have magnitude $r$ and argument $\theta$. I want to generate the following image in Mathematica:[image]

and then I want to see what happens to the image as I change the magnitude of $\varepsilon$ with a slider. In particular, I want to see how the origin-centered circular arc connecting $1+\varepsilon$ to the point $r$ on the real axis approaches the perpendicular from $1+\varepsilon$ to the real axis as the magnitude of $\varepsilon$ approaches $0$. What would be a good way to do this?

This is what I came up with so far:

```
e := 
  Manipulate[
    FromPolarCoordinates[{mag, Pi/6}], {mag, 0, 1}]; 
    eps := {1, 0} + {e[[0]], e[[1]]}; 
    Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0} + eps}]
  ]
```

Comment: I'm new to mathematica so I haven't gotten very far. I tried using the Graphics and Line functions to plot the vectors, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Ok, it's pretty terrible, but this is what I came up with:

e := Manipulate[FromPolarCoordinates[{mag, Pi/6}], {mag, 0, 1}];
eps := {1, 0} + {e[[0]], e[[1]]};
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0} + eps}]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve seems functionally equivalent to showing graphically that $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1$. Here is an example to achieve that:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
     {Thick, Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
     {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}}]},
     {Black, Dashed, Line[{{Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, {Cos[theta], 0}}]},
     {Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, theta}]}
    },
    Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}
  ],
  {theta, Pi/2, 0}
]
```

[image: Manipulate output similar to required plot]

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if I understood you right. Can modify as needed.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x = 1 + realEps, y = imEps, r},
  r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
  Grid[{{Row[{"r =", r}]},
    {Graphics[{
       {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {x, y}}]},
       {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, r, {0, ArcTan[x, y]}]},
       {Text[
         Style[Row[{ArcTan[x, y]*180/Pi , " deg"}], Small], {.7, 0.2}]}
       }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
      ImageSize -> 300
      ]}
    }]
  ]
 ,
 {{realEps, .5, "real part \[Epsilon]"}, 0, 2, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{imEps, 1, "imaginary part \[Epsilon]"}, 0, 3, .01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {realEps, imEps}
 ]
```